# Creating Method to show the status of an object

Tags: java

So the title does not make much sense and I apologize, so hopefully this will clear things up. I am creating a Library check in system. I have an ArrayList of books that I need to create methods to show the status of the books. My issue is, is that I am unsure how to create these methods with what I have already been given. Here is the code:
    import java.util.*;

```
public class Catalog{


private ArrayList<Book> books;
    Book b1 = new Book("Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire", "J.K. Rowling", "0439139600", 2000, Status.LOST);
    Book b2 = new Book("The Hunger Games", "Suzanne Collins", "0439023483", 2008, Status.ONLOAN);
    Book b3 = new Book("The Help", "Kathryn Stockett", "9780399155345", 2009, Status.INLIBRARY);
    Book b4 = new Book("The Road", "Cormac McCarthy", "9780307265432", 2006, Status.INLIBRARY);
    Book b5 = new Book("The Lightning Thief", "Rick Riordan", "0786838655", 2005, Status.ONLOAN);
    Book b6 = new Book("The Da Vinci Code", "Dan Brown", "0307277674", 2003, Status.LOST);
    Book b7 = new Book("Life of Pi", "Yann Martel", "0770430074", 2001, Status.ONLOAN);
    Book b8 = new Book("The Book Thief", "Marcus Zusak", "9780375831003", 2005, Status.INLIBRARY);
    Book b9 = new Book("The Time Traveler's Wife", "Audrey Niffenegger", "9781939126016", 2003, Status.LOST);


//Empty-argument constructor that initializes the books ArrayList.
public Catalog() {
    ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

}//end empty constructor


//Method for adding books to the array List
public ArrayList<Book> addBook(Book b) {
    books.add(b); //not sure if this is done correctly
    return books; 

}//end addBook

//Method that should return a list of the titles of all books
//and their status(LOST,INLIBRARY,ONLOAN).
public ArrayList<Book> showAllBooks() {


}//end showAllBooks

//Method that should return an list of the titles in the catalog that are marked LOST
public String showLost() {


}
}//end class
```

In addition to this I created an enum class called Status that holds the constants to indicate the status of the books. Here's the code:

```
   /**
 * Data Type to hold constants to
 * indicate status of Book Object in a Library.
 * @author 
 * @version 1.0
 * Programming Project 2 Starter
 * 2/10/17
 */
public enum Status {

LOST,
INLIBRARY,
ONLOAN

}//end enum
```

Book class:
       public class Book  {

```
private Status status;
private String title, authors, isbn;
private int yearPublished;
private Status status;
private String publisherName;


public Book() {

    title = null;
    authors = null;
    isbn = null;
    yearPublished = 0;
    status = null;
    publisherName = null;

}//end book constructor

public Book(String isbn, String title, String authors, int yearPublished, Status status) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.authors = authors;
    this.yearPublished = yearPublished;
    this.status = status;


}//end book constructor

public Status getStatus() {
    return this.status;
   }//end getStatus
```

Comment: The constructor doesn't initialize the `books` you think it does. It initializes a local variable (also called `books`), and after the constructor ends it vanishes. As for the question, it's too broad. You can't just show "I have this code and I don't know what to do". Edit the question to show a **specific** question, preferably after showing actual effort.

Comment: OK, but what are you unsure about exactly?  Please show some code for `Book` and pick one method you are having trouble with, your question as-is is a little broad.

Comment: @Eric Graham, Show us the Book class. With that, we can help you.

Comment: `AddBook()` should probably be type `void`. `ShowAllBooks()` should probably be void also. What's the scope of `List books`?

Comment: the Book class is added, thanks @ThexPhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Book class, you need to have a getter method for type Status. Call this method where you want to get the status.

Example -

```
private Status status; 

public Status getStatus(){
  return this.status;
}
```

Comment: ahhhh ok thanks! ... I don't know why I didn't get that to begin with tbh

Comment: Downvoting answers for easy question is not correct @Downvoter if you consider that most of these posts deserve downvotes and  no upvotes, you should maybe avoid visiting this site because many rookies ask easy questions and are not necessarily able to understand answers from other posts.